# How to pass AWS keys to access S3 with Apache Hudi on LocalStack?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, localstack, apache-hudi

I am using the Docker image of `localstack/localstack:2.0.2` and attempting to write on S3 in it using PySpark(3.1.1) /Apache-Hudi (0.13.0) with the following options:

```
        {
            'hoodie.table.name': 'foo',
            ...
            'hoodie.write.commit.callback.on': True,
            'hoodie.write.commit.callback.http.api.key': 'test',
            'hoodie.write.commit.callback.http.url': 'http://localstack:4566',
            'hoodie.aws.access.key': 'test',
            'hoodie.aws.secret.key': 'test',
        }
```

However when I save data with:

```
data_frame.write\
            .format('hudi')\
            .options(**hudi_options)\
            .mode(write_mode) \
            .save(target.uri)
```

Also I followed the instructions in https://hudi.apache.org/docs/s3_hoodie/ adding the required jars and configuration to my Spark conf but still the same issue:

> An error occurred while calling o1576.save. :
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
> s3://my.bucket.output/my.root_dir.output/location/.hoodie:
> getFileStatus on
> s3://my.bucket.output/my.root_dir.output/location/.hoodie:
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service:
> Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID:
> ZRH67VD9S6FAB0JD; S3 Extended Request ID:
> HruYemqpRwo7lEVDX/KyeaJXFLPGkMs1iybKgLPvY6seWlUCwVo/A9WLwK8dsyJWtj5zesOMOsKXooLnb50XQA==;
> Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID:
> HruYemqpRwo7lEVDX/KyeaJXFLPGkMs1iybKgLPvY6seWlUCwVo/A9WLwK8dsyJWtj5zesOMOsKXooLnb50XQA==
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:158)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:101)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1568)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:117)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1437)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.exists(S3AFileSystem.java:2040)
> at org.apache.hudi.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:122)
> at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:150)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service:
> Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID:
> ZRH67VD9S6FAB0JD; S3 Extended Request ID:
> HruYemqpRwo7lEVDX/KyeaJXFLPGkMs1iybKgLPvY6seWlUCwVo/A9WLwK8dsyJWtj5zesOMOsKXooLnb50XQA==;
> Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID:
> HruYemqpRwo7lEVDX/KyeaJXFLPGkMs1iybKgLPvY6seWlUCwVo/A9WLwK8dsyJWtj5zesOMOsKXooLnb50XQA==
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
> at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
> at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
> at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1338)
> at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1312)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:904)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1553)
> ... 37 more

How can I avoid the issue?